# how do i use imagick in php? (resize & crop)

Tags: php, resize, crop, imagick

I use imagick for thumbnail crop, but sometimes cropped thumbnails are missing top part of the images (hair, eyes).

I was thinking to resize the image then crop it. Also, I need to keep the image size ratio.

Below is the php script I use for crop:

```
$im = new imagick( "img/20130815233205-8.jpg" );
$im->cropThumbnailImage( 80, 80 );
$im->writeImage( "thumb/th_80x80_test.jpg" );
echo '<img src="thumb/th_80x80_test.jpg">';
```

Thanks..

Comment: What errors are you getting? what is the expected output? What version of PHP? is imagick installed? More details please...

Comment: No, this is not about an error. imagick works fine. Above script does crop only. I want to RESIZE first, then I want to crop it, so I'm missing first step..

Comment: Well, call `imageResize` first, then...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This task is not easy as the "important" part may not always be at the same place. Still, using something like this

```
$im = new imagick("c:\\temp\\523764_169105429888246_1540489537_n.jpg");
$imageprops = $im->getImageGeometry();
$width = $imageprops['width'];
$height = $imageprops['height'];
if($width > $height){
    $newHeight = 80;
    $newWidth = (80 / $height) * $width;
}else{
    $newWidth = 80;
    $newHeight = (80 / $width) * $height;
}
$im->resizeImage($newWidth,$newHeight, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
$im->cropImage (80,80,0,0);
$im->writeImage( "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\th_80x80_test.jpg" );
echo '<img src="th_80x80_test.jpg">';
```

(tested)

should work. The cropImage parameters (0 and 0) determine the upper left corner of the cropping area. So playing with these gives you differnt results of what stays in the image.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18315232/5111076) I made a more general function that resizes and crops `Imagick` image to fit given width and height (i.e. behaves exactly as CSS `background-size: cover` declaration):

```
/**
 * Resizes and crops $image to fit provided $width and $height.
 *
 * @param \Imagick $image
 *   Image to change.
 * @param int $width
 *   New desired width.
 * @param int $height
 *   New desired height.
 */
function image_cover(Imagick $image, $width, $height) {
  $ratio = $width / $height;

  // Original image dimensions.
  $old_width = $image->getImageWidth();
  $old_height = $image->getImageHeight();
  $old_ratio = $old_width / $old_height;

  // Determine new image dimensions to scale to.
  // Also determine cropping coordinates.
  if ($ratio > $old_ratio) {
    $new_width = $width;
    $new_height = $width / $old_width * $old_height;
    $crop_x = 0;
    $crop_y = intval(($new_height - $height) / 2);
  }
  else {
    $new_width = $height / $old_height * $old_width;
    $new_height = $height;
    $crop_x = intval(($new_width - $width) / 2);
    $crop_y = 0;
  }

  // Scale image to fit minimal of provided dimensions.
  $image->resizeImage($new_width, $new_height, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);

  // Now crop image to exactly fit provided dimensions.
  $image->cropImage($new_width, $new_height, $crop_x, $crop_y);
}
```

Hope this may help somebody.

Comment: ``imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS`` should be ``\Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS``

Comment: Last line `$image->cropImage($new_width, $new_height, ...` should be `$image->cropImage($width, $height, ...`

Comment: For me it works with
`$image->cropImage($new_width, $new_height, 0,0);`

Answer (score 0):

My code. Please vote

```
// Imagick
$image = new Imagick($img);

// method 1 - resize to max width
if($type==1){
    $image->resizeImage($newWidth,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
// method 2 - resize to max height
}else if($type==2){
    $image->resizeImage(0,$newHeight,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
// method 1 - resize to max width or height
}else if($type==3){
    if($image->getImageHeight() <= $image->getImageWidth()){
        $image->resizeImage($newWidth,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
    }else{
        $image->resizeImage(0,$newHeight,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
    }
// method 4 - resize and crop to center
}else if($type==4){
    if($image->getImageHeight() <= $image->getImageWidth()){
        $image->resizeImage(0,$newheight,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
    }else{
        $image->resizeImage($newwidth,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
    }
    $cropWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
    $cropHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
    
    $image->cropimage(
        $newwidth,
        $newheight,
        ($cropWidth - $newwidth) / 2,
        ($cropHeight - $newheight) / 2
    );
}

$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->writeImages($newImg, true);
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();
```