# Imagick photo multiple image resize crop without distorting /stretching php

Tags: imagick, codeigniter-3, aspect-ratio

I wish to keep the aspect ratio of images as I resize them. I got 94 000 images I need to display as preview images on a social site. The challenge I got is some users uploaded full length photos as a result they appear stretched after re-sizing. I am using codeigniter to implement this. The file names are in a database table. This is the code I am using

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/profiles    /purchased_profiles/".$images_->_file_name)) {
    //echo "The file $filename exists";

    $thumb = new Imagick();

    $thumb->readImage($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/profiles/purchased_profiles/".$images_->_file_name); 
    $orientation = $thumb->getImageOrientation(); 

    switch($orientation) { 
        case imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT: 
            $thumb->rotateimage("#000", 180); // rotate 180 degrees 
        break; 

        case imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP: 
            $thumb->rotateimage("#000", 90); // rotate 90 degrees CW 
        break; 

        case imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM: 
            $thumb->rotateimage("#000", -90); // rotate 90 degrees CCW 
        break; 
    }
    $thumb->resizeImage(160,160,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);

    $thumb->writeImage($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/profiles/purchased_profiles/160x160/".$images_->_file_name);
    $thumb->clear();
    $thumb->destroy(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are uploaded with different sizes its a real challenge If I am to combine the solution found here [how do i use imagick in php? (resize & crop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312243/how-do-i-use-imagick-in-php-resize-crop?rq=1) and your code I may come up with the following

```
      if (file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/profiles/purchased_profiles/".$images_->_file_name)) {



        $thumb = new Imagick();

       $thumb->readImage($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/profiles/purchased_profiles/".$images_->_file_name); 

$orientation = $thumb->getImageOrientation(); 

switch($orientation) { 
    case imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT: 
        $thumb->rotateimage("#000", 180); // rotate 180 degrees 
    break; 

    case imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP: 
        $thumb->rotateimage("#000", 90); // rotate 90 degrees CW 
    break; 

    case imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM: 
        $thumb->rotateimage("#000", -90); // rotate 90 degrees CCW 
    break; 
}

          //now check the width
        $width=$thumb->getImageWidth();

        //now check height
        $height=$thumb->getImageHeight();

       if ($height>$width) {

         $new_height=160;
         $new_width=(int)($width/$height*160);

         $thumb->resizeImage($new_width,$new_height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);

         $cropWidth = $thumb->getImageWidth();
         $cropHeight = $thumb->getImageHeight();
      $cropZoom=1;

     if ($cropZoom) {
       $newWidth = $cropWidth / 2;
       $newHeight = $cropHeight / 2;

    $thumb->cropimage(
        $new_width,
        $new_width,
        0,
        0
    );


      }
   } 
     elseif ($width>$height) {
     # code...

        $new_width=160;

        $new_height=(int)($height/$width*160);

       $thumb->resizeImage($new_width,$new_height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
         }
       else{

        $thumb->resizeImage(160,160,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
        }   



           $thumb->writeImage($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/profiles/purchased_profiles/160x160/".$images_->_file_name);
        $thumb->clear();
       $thumb->destroy(); }
```

You may need to crop if the image height is greater than the width so I decided to crop with dimensions equal to the width  from the to left corner most likely you wont miss the face of the person this way. Good luck